# How to run one way ANOVA in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I've a dataset looking like this:

```
> print(mydata)
                col1                 col2                col3
1               0.819               0.851               0.874
2               0.972               0.703               0.821
3               0.891               0.790               0.951
4               0.839               0.799               0.819
```

I would like to know if there are significant differences between the three groups `col1`, `col2` and `col3`. For this matter, my guess is that the best way is to run an `anova` test.

Please find below the script I used to produce the dataset, to run the test and the Error displayed by R:

```
> mydata <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
> accuracymetrics <- as.vector(mydata)
> anova(accuracymetrics)
```

> Error in UseMethod("anova") :    no applicable method for 'anova'
>   applied to an object of class "data.frame"

It's the first time I'm running such an analysis in R so bear with me if this question is not interesting for the forum. Any input to solve this error is appreciated!

Comment: Look at the help page for the `anova` function: "object 
an object containing the results returned by a model fitting function (e.g., lm or glm)." It's meant to be called on a model, not a data frame. That's reflected in your error message.

Comment: What do you mean with `significant differences`. Usually you perform the t-test to see if the means of the samples are the same (under the assumption that they come from a normal distribution) or the kolmogorov-smirnov test to see if they come from the same distribution. Anova is based on a regression model usually.

Comment: @LyzandeR Here, I need to compare between more than two groups, so according to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3916511/ I need to use an ANOVA.

Comment: So, that's the t-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood you correctly the three groups you are talking about are the three columns in your data.
If this is the case you need to do two things:

First, reshape your data from wide to long format such that it looks like this

```
group | value
------------
grp1  | 0.819
grp1  | 0.972
```

This can easily be done with the `tidyr` package

```
library(tidyr)
longdata <- gather(mydata, group, value)
```

Second: you have to use `aov` instead of `anova`:

```
res.aov <- aov(value ~ group, data = longdata)
summary(res.aov)
```

[Here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-way-anova-test-in-r) you can find even more details.
Hope this helps.